# How to read from channel while go routines are running

Tags: go

I am looking to fire off an unknown number of goroutines. In this example adding to the `number` channel. Then read messages off the `messages` channel as they roll in.

Why am I only seeing one message when I would expect to see all 100 messages in this code? How do I see the messages for all of the numbers added?

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/E7-Pqm-eAkh)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func Run(numbers chan int, messages chan string) {
    stuff := <-numbers
    messages <- fmt.Sprintf("Ran %d", stuff)
}

func main() {
    var numbers = make(chan int)
    var messages = make(chan string)

    go Run(numbers, messages)

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        go func(i int) { numbers <-i }(i) 
    }

    msg := <-messages
    fmt.Println(msg)
}
```

Comment: You're receiving one value from `messages`. I don't understand how you expect that line of code to execute 100 times

Comment: @JimB I guess I need to range over the messages to read them.

Comment: BTW: You can annotate channel parameters as input parameters and as output parameters. That would make it clear which way info flows in `Run()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Run` reads one message from `numbers`, writes one message to `messages`, and terminates. Try this instead:

```
func Run(numbers chan int, messages chan string) {
    for stuff := range numbers {
       messages <- fmt.Sprintf("Ran %d", stuff)
    }
}
```

This will run until `numbers` is closed.

Comment: Ok so in the question when I call Run it only grabs one item from numbers. In order to get all the numbers  you range over the channel.

Comment: Yes. Also note that the way it is written, the program will read only one msg from `messages`, so `Run` will be stuck after writing once to `messages`, and you'll end up with 98 goroutines waiting to write to `numbers`.